# How to swap images on HTML without libraries (like z-index)

Tags: html, canvas, z-index, swap, drawimage

I have a question !
In a html5 canvas, I create an "x" number of images. The last image created is always above the other. Is it possible to swap the depths of the images without the need for libraries? (I do not intend to reverse the order of the variables)
I want somethin like this (without kinetic):
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-shape-layering-with-kineticjs/

so, here is the code I'm using:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");  


    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
    };
    imageObj.src = "image1.png";

    var imageObj2 = new Image();
    imageObj2.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(imageObj2, 40, 30);
    };
    imageObj2.src = "image2.png";

    /* I want to put "Image1.png" over "Image2.png" dynamically, for example, pressing a button, all this after render on the canvas */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the furtherest images first. It might help to put the images in an array so you can just loop through them.

Otherwise, in the case of your example, this will fix it as you are drawing `context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);` last. Think of it as if you would draw it on paper; what you draw last is above what you have already drawn.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");  

var imageObj2 = new Image();
imageObj2.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imageObj2, 40, 30);
};
imageObj2.src = "image2.png";

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
};
imageObj.src = "image1.png";
```

Answer (score 1):

The order you draw the images matters. You will need to draw the images in the back first, then draw the closer ones.

Comment: The problem is that I am creating a kind of forest, I think about 30 or 40 trees, which are close to the user as if he were walking. But the trees that generated at the end, are above those who were first. (Attached picture) [link](http://postimage.org/image/icd9blbth/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a canvas object for every image and either show / hide them or adjust the z-index?

Comment: If you do it that way... You may as well not have canvases at all.